# Cant load json file content in flutter app

Tags: json, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

> Hi I have just started developing using flutter and came across this
> problem when trying to follow an online beginner tutorial. The json
> decoding works fine but the initData function doesnt get executed

```
json file:
[
    {
        "title": "Glutes",
        "img": "assets/ex1.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "Abs",
        "img": "assets/ex2.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "Legs",
        "img": "assets/ex3.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "Arms",
        "img": "assets/ex4.png"
    }
]
```

> main.dart is working fine as the app runs
>
> home_page.dart relevant parts where decoded json is used

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'colors.dart' as color;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List info = [];

  _initData() {
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/info.json").then((value) {
      info = json.decode(value);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initData();
  }

Widget Build(context).......
Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: info.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 170,
                            width: 200,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(info[i]["img"])),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 3,
                                      offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                                      color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond
                                          .withOpacity(0.1)),
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 3,
                                      offset: const Offset(-5, -5),
                                      color: color.AppColor.gradientSecond
                                          .withOpacity(0.1))
                                ]),
                            child: Center(
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Text(
                                      info[i]["title"],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: color.AppColor.homePageDetail),
                                    ))),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    }))
```

> Used print statements like a noob to figure out the problem. initData
> function works but the info list turns up empty for which the image
> and title are not rendered.

```
    Pubspec file
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - json/
```

Comment: Could it be because it takes time to load data? And, I could see an `await` missing there.

Maybe try modifying the `_initData()` as:
```dart
_initData() {
    await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/info.json").then((value) {
      info = json.decode(value);
    });
  }
```

Comment: not working either. Also, I cant put dart before the name of the function shows an error message

Comment: try a setstate here `info = json.decode(value);`

Comment: that worked for me thanks. Mind giving me an explanation?

Comment: It was all working as expected, but because you were not updating the UI after the data was fetched. It looked like nothing was happening.